# What is the type of data we receive from signalr hub?

Tags: signalr, blob

I am writing a streaming component by sending mediarecorder blob(event.data) to a SignalR hub and return the same blob to other users connected using SendAsync method. But, the object I receive from hub is different from what I passed to hub. Because, my client side JS code does not recognize it like an event.data object.
My question is how the object will change after passing to hub? Here is the hub code and how I can turn it to initial value after receiving back from hub

```
    public async Task SendBlob(Object blob)
            {
                await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceivingBlob", blob);
            }
```

Comment: I believe that the object sent is serialized so you can just receive it string (json).

Comment: Do you mean that it is not possible to deserialize it to original binary object?

Comment: It is possible. You just pass the object to be received in the method where you have `Object` to your object like `public async Task SendBlob(YourBlobObject blob)`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work. The object that it received from hub in my JS code is different from the one sent to hub. The reason it that I can apply "arrayBuffer()" on sent object , but not on received object. 
Also, I don't know what is the relevant type of sent data in C# to be declared in method signature(YourBlobObject blob). Is it a Byte array?.

Comment: `YourBlobObject` would be the type of the object that you want to receive. You can say that is the copy of the object that you have from JS code but in c# language. You can see this repo for SignalR: https://github.com/Kiril1512/SignalRDemo
There you can see that hub has a `NewMessage` that will send a `ChatMessage` object. This is the same object as the Angular code on the front-end. Take a look at the repo...